# How can I show the right equation of the rate of change?

Tags: calculus

A snowball is melting proportional to its surface.

From this information alone we are going to derive the volume V(t) of the ball as a function of time that follows

$V'(t) = - k V(t)^{\frac{2}{3}}$

I know that the volume of the sphere is $V = \frac{3}{4} \pi r^3$

Comment: I would probably just write the equation of the surface area of the ball, instead of $V^{2/3}$, even though the difference can be included into the constant $k$. So what is the difficulty you are facing? Do you have to solve the equation?

Comment: I just wasn't sure if I could simply use the area itself. But now you gave the green light, I def can do it.

Comment: $V=\frac43 \pi r^3$ is the correct formula

Comment: The volume of a sphere is $V = \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$ and its surface area is $S = 4\pi r^2$.

Comment: If k is the rate of melting, then you need to adjust your on the mark equation by a not pretty numerical factor as pointed out by N.F. Taussig,